# Composed relation of 2 relations on the set A

Tags: set, relation, discrete-mathematics

I'm struck with this problem, and i'm wondering if I'm wrong or the answer sheet I have is wrong. I've included the problem description and answer below:

[image]

The problem is with 2 and 3. First I construct the matrix for R and S:

[image]

Then I can compute the 5th row of the R ◦ S using this equation:

[image]

When i try with (5, 4) as shown in the solution i get 0, how ever if i try with 3 i get 1.

[image]

Same happens in the 3rd problem where I get the result 4, but I should get 3. Have I swapped something along the way since my to answers are just the opposite answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should read the text of the formula again:

> We get the matrix for S ○ R by taking the matrix product [R] * [S] ...

So if you want to get R ○ S you have to calculate [S] * [R] (note: the position is swapped).

R ○ S ⇒ [S] * [R] (5,4) = (0 ∧ 0) ∨ (0 ∧ 0) ∨ (1 ∧ 1) ∨ (0 ∧ 0) ∨ (0 ∧ 0) = 1